# How to identify magento xml nodes

Tags: xml, magento

Is their any proper way to identify node name in *.xml files in Magento.
For eg.

```
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" module="Trimantra_Helloworld">
                <name>helloworld</name>
                <path>helloworld</path>
                <label>Hello World</label>
             </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
```

This block of xml code adds a link to customer navigation block in my account page.

Is their any way to identify that we should use  "`<customer_account>`" and not any other thing in order to add link.

Its become difficult to identify which node to use in order to update a particular section in front-end as well as back-end.

For eg. If any one wants to add new section to order invoice page (admin panel), how can we identify which node to use in custom module xml file.

I hope  my question is clear enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This node represent module,controller and  action.

```
<customer_account> represents module=>customer,controller=>account,action=>*
<customer_account_login> will represent module=>customer,controller=>account,action=>login
```

SImilarly for sales invoice view page, module is adminhtml, controller is sales_order_invoice and action is view so tag becomes `<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>`
OR simply you can follow browser url to determine its tag but beware in backend url's admin actually represent adminhtml module